# Why am I am not getting a runtime exception with message "no empty, please" when running following code

Tags: kotlin, getter-setter

Why am I am not getting a runtime exception with message "no empty, please" when running following code:
code:

```kotlin
class Car(val name: String, col: String) {
    val fuel = 100
    var color = col
        set(value) {
            if (value.isBlank()) {
                throw RuntimeException("no empty, please")
            }
            field = value
        }
}
```

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var car = Car("Maruti", "")
    println("Your car ${car.name} is of ${car.color}")
}
```

Comment: Just tried it and it returns "Your car Maruti is of".

Comment: The setter of `color` is not called for it's initial value. If you want to validate the `col` parameter, you could init `color` with an empty string and set the actual value within the `init` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an object gets initialized, the setter is not used. In your class, the value of the property `color` would be directly initialized using the `col` parameter from the constructor.

```
class Car(val name: String, col: String) {
    val fuel = 100
    // color is getting its initial value from the 
    // constructor directly. Setter won't be used here
    var color = col
        set(value) {
            if (value.isBlank()) {
                throw RuntimeException("no empty, please")
            }
            field = value
        }
}
```

In your main function, you are not calling the setter.

```
fun main() {
    // here only arguments are being passed to the constructor
    var car = Car("Maruti", "")
    println("Your car ${car.name} is of ${car.color}")
}
```

However, if you try to use the setter with an empty string the exception would be thrown.

```
fun main() {
        // here only arguments are being passed to the constructor
        var car = Car("Maruti", "")

        // this line would call the setter and 
        // exception would be thrown 
        car.color = ""

        println("Your car ${car.name} is of ${car.color}")
}
```

If you want to validate parameters during the object's initialization then you can use `init` blocks to put your logic. The codes in `init` blocks are executed when the object is initialized for the first time. Arguments passed in the constructor and previously initialized properties (in the constructor as well as before the `init` block in terms of line numbers) are in the scope of the `init` blocks.

```
class Car(val name: String, col: String) {

    init {
        if (col.isBlank()) throw RuntimeException("no empty, please")
    }

    val fuel = 100

    var color = col
        set(value) {
            if (value.isBlank()) {
                throw RuntimeException("no empty, please")
            }
            field = value
        }
}
```

Because of the validation in the `init` block, it would throw `RuntimeException` if you try to initialize it with an empty string.

A more idiomatic way to do this kind of validation is using `require` function from the Kotlin standard library.

```
init {
        require(col.isNotBlank()) {"no empty, please"}
}
```

`require` would throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the check turns out to be false with the given message.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation  as well as for suggestion of an alternate function. It completely clarified my doubts.

Comment: @AbhinandanThakur glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example you initialize the backing field [directly](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields). It means that no setter will be called. Obviously, this code will call the setter:

```kotlin
car.color = ""
```

Or you can call setter inside the `init` block of the `Car` class:

```kotlin
class Car(col: String) {
    ...
    init {
        color = col
    }
}
```

If you set empty color, RuntimeException will be thrown.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and explanation. I have understood the concept now.